# Returning a 404 for a missing file under a specific directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, error-handling

In Apache, is it possible in the .htaccess to return a different 404 page based on the filepath?

For example:

```
For missing pages under http://example.com/support/*
Redirect to 404-support.php

For all else
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a directory named 'support', you could put in a .htaccess file inside that directory and it will override the configuration of the parent directories. So, in your / folder, you could specify it to be

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

But for the support folder, put in a new .htaccess file and type in:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /support/404.php
```